Ignore whitespace in the end of the string
I am using RegExp. I am trying to filter elements according to a list of specific values I have. Some of the elements have whitespace in the end of the value. Trying to use \s+ or s* or other options, sadly do not work.
I ended up using Playwright's or functionality, once without whitespace and once with whitespace. There must be a better option, but none seem to work for me.
.getByText(new RegExp(`^${value}$`))
    .or(page.getByText(new RegExp(`^${value} $`)))

Editing:
My input contains a list of names (Daniel, Tanya, Vered). The elements on the webpage might contain a whitespace in the end of the string.

how does your input look like? can you post an example?

new RegExp needs the slash escaped: page.getByText(new RegExp(\^${value}\s*$`)).click();`

@Mr.Irrelevant I edited my question and added examples.

@mplungjan Thank you very much! Indeed I was trying "\s*" and TypeScript was complaining that the escape character is redundant.

If you have a list, then try const regexParts = names.map(name => \^${name}\s*$`); const regexPattern = regexParts.join('|'); page.getByText(new RegExp(regexPattern)).click();`

You should share the elements you're manipulating and provide full context for what you're trying to test. Regex may not be the best way to select them, so this may be an xy problem (focusing too much on the attempted solution rather than the real problem), because using regex like this is often an antipattern. Playwright automatically handles whitespace and these matchers accept arrays, so there should be no need for regex here.
